# Use Applescript to open a file under a specified folder

Tags: applescript, filepath

Say I have a bunch of folders with similar subpaths:

```
Folder 1
  Do
    Re
      Mi
        <Files>
Folder 2
  Do
    Re
      Mi
        <Different Files>
```

I know I can use `tell application Finder to open "Macintosh HD:Users: ...` to open a folder. Is there any way to queue a popup to select which of `Folder 1` or `Folder 2` I would like to enter, then input it into the above command? For instance, if I select `Folder 1`, it would go to `...Folder 1/Do/Re/Mi`, whereas if I select `Folder 2`, it would go to `...Folder 2/Do/Re/Mi`.

One thing I tried is combining `do shell script` with concatenate to get `do shell script "open " & variable & "/Do/Re/Mi/"`, but the code fails if the file name is more than one word.

Comment: You can fix the error with the `do shell script` by warping the path in quotation marks: `do shell script "open \"" & variable & "/Do/Re/Mi/\""`?

Answer (score 0):

- Set a base folder
- Retrieve all folder names of the base folder
- Create a list
- Choose an item
- Concatenate the path and open the folder

For example (set `baseFolder` to the alias of the parent folder of `Folder 1` and `Folder 2`)

```
set baseFolder to path to home folder
set folderList to {}
tell application "Finder" to set allFolders to name of folders of baseFolder
repeat with i from 1 to (count allFolders)
    set end of folderList to (i as text) & space & item i of allFolders
end repeat
set chosenItem to choose from list folderList
if chosenItem is false then return
set chosenIndex to word 1 of item 1 of chosenItem
set selectedFolder to item chosenIndex of allFolders
set destinationFolder to (baseFolder as text) & selectedFolder & ":Do:Re:Mi:"

tell application "Finder"
    if exists folder destinationFolder then
        open folder destinationFolder
    else
        display dialog "Sorry, the folder does not exist"
    end if
end tell
```